# IIS redirecting issue for multiple webapi

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We have two WebAPI applications hosted in IIS. 
IIS is having ad authenticated default site and inside the site we have two API applications pointing to different folders. Both folders are having same code. Only the client id in both application has been changed.

If I call the first API as `('https://******/a')` I am able to get the default WebAPI page, and able to redirect to `https://******/a/help` and other API methods.

But If I call the second API as `('https://******/b')` I am able to get the default WebAPI page, but not able to redirect to `https://******/a/help`.

It is redirecting to default site `(https://******)`

We have checked the configurations of both applications. Both are same.

Comment: Any code to demonstrate how you have it configured or are we supposed to guess? What's the redirect logic, Routing.cs, individual class routes, individual method routes or are you doing redirects? How is it redirecting client B?

Comment: no other major configurations.in iis we have created the webapi applicatons , and binded  it to the repective folders. So when we run the application  
 https://******/a/api/test  : I am getting output   but  https://******/b/api/test :   I am getting 302 redirect and redirected to default site.so our guess is somewhere error, but doesnot know,how to figure  it out.

Comment: I'm still confused about why your application redirect to the defaut site. I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing(enable 200 status tracing ) to check if there is any useful information in the logs. More details about how to use FRT, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).